# What is a Titanic Number™?

Tags: pattern

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, and the likewise inspired [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I like to call it a ***Titanic Number™***. Find out when a number is called a *Titanic Number™* and when it is called a *Non-Titanic Number™*.

| Titanic Number™ | Non-Titanic Number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 837997112 | 877911168 |
| 7869101687669 | 83796873117109 |
| 77658298108101 | 83112797810369 |
| 677910578 | 8265102116 |
| 676582 | 7973108 |
| 83657868 | 7399101 |
| 114796775 | 677982107 |
| 10376978383 | 651128076101 |
| 11279116658479 | 6665767611179110 |
| 1091011149911711489 | 115116898211170796577 |

---

**CSV Version:**

```
Titanic Number™,Non-Titanic Number™
837997112,877911168
7869101687669,83796873117109
77658298108101,83112797810369
677910578,8265102116
676582,7973108
83657868,7399101
114796775,677982107
10376978383,651128076101
11279116658479,6665767611179110
1091011149911711489,115116898211170796577
```

Comment: rot13(Qbrf pncvgnyvmngvba znggre be vf vg whfg gurer sbe checbfrf bs pbaprnyvat? Lbh qba'g unir gb nafjre :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Titanic Number™ represents things sinking in the water and Non-Titanic Number™ things floating in the water.

> Step 1: split the strings to decimal ASCII e.g.: 837997112 --> 83 79 97 112

> Step 2: convert to words
> 83 79 97 112,87 79 111 68
> SOap,WOoD
> 78 69 101 68 76 69,83 79 68 73 117 109
> NEeDLE,SODIum
> 77 65 82 98 108 101,83 112 79 78 103 69
> MARble,SpONgE
> 67 79 105 78,82 65 102 116
> COiN,RAft
> 67 65 82,79 73 108
> CAR,OIl
> 83 65 78 68,73 99 101
> SAND,Ice
> 114 79 67 75,67 79 82 107
> rOCK,CORk
> 103 76 97 83 83,65 112 80 76 101
> gLaSS, ApPLe
> 112 79 116 65 84 79,66 65 76 76 111 79 110
> pOtATO,BALLoOn
> 09 101 114 99 117 114 89,115 116 89 82 111 70 79 65 77
> mercurY,stYRoFOAM